# Angular. Can't jump to file with error. File path isn't a link

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJwXe.png)

If there is a compilation error i can see it, but cant jump to the file with the error

Comment: Which IDE version do you use?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1 (Ultimate Edition)
I guess it depends on project structure. I've created a new angular project from zero for a test and it works

Comment: Could you please compose a sample project where it is reproducible?

Comment: I found out what was the problem. I had opened the project like: ./outer-folder/folder-with-angular. And when I opened it just like ./folder-with-angular everything works. Idea couldn't recognize angular app. @Oksana